# MySql Double join with a table and a view table

Tags: mysql

I have a table and a view table

with the following columns:

```
View1
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
pcode varchar(255) 
ref1 varchar(255) 
des varchar(255)

Table1
Columns:
id int(11) 
pcode varchar(255) 
brand varchar(255) 
description varchar(255) 
size varchar(255) 
barcode varchar(255)
```

I am trying to run a query to double join the two.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
select * from table1
join view1 on table1.description  = view1.desc
join view1 on table1.pcode = view1.pcode;
```

but this gives me back an error message `Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'view1'`

have also tried this:

```
select table1.pcode from((view1
join table1 on view1.description = table1.des)
join table1 on view1.pcode = table1.pcode);
```

just gives me the same error code..

Comment: You need to alias the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an alias for `view1` because of there are two `view1` on your query.

```
select * from table1
join view1 v1 on table1.description  = v1.desc
join view1 v2 on table1.pcode = v2.pcode;
```

Comment: Would this also apply to tables? or is this just views?

Comment: Tables as well @Eduard

Answer (score 0):

you've to provider alias name  like below -

```
select * from table1
join view1 a on table1.description  = a.desc
join view1 b on table1.pcode = b.pcode
```